# How can I know if a coordinate (lat & lot) are within the range of other two coordinates?

Tags: javascript, typescript, geolocation, coordinates

I have what I believe to be an easy problem to solve, but still I'm struggling to find the answer, maybe cause I'm not very good with Math or doesn't understand exactly how coordinates works.

I have two points that represent geolocations, `a` and `b`:

```
const a = {
  lat: 0,
  lon: 0,
}

const b = {
  lat: 0,
  lon: 0
}
```

And given an input `c`, is `c` within `a` and `b`?

`a` represents the top left-corner, and `b` represents a bottom-right corner, e.g:

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19ihm.png) and [example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVtRV.png)

A roughly example of the implementation is:

```
type Coordinate = {
  lat: number
  lon: number
}

const a: Coordinate = {
  lat: 48.881366,
  lon: 2.327037
}

const b: Coordinate = {
  lat: 48.878525,
  lon: 2.331655
}


function isWithinGeoRange(c: Coordinate): boolean {
  return false
}

const c = {
  lat: 48.879971,
  lon: 2.329885
}

isWithinGeoRange(c) // true | false
```

I know I'm supposed to show examples and things that I've tried, but I didn't try anything because it's my first time messing around with maps and geolocations, so I don't know exactly where to start.

Thank you.

Comment: Spherical coordinate math is a complex topic. The best answer would probably be to find a library that deals with the topic, rather than code it yourself.   [This NPM search](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=lattitude) turns up a few candidates.

Answer (score 0):

The formula to determine if a point is within a rectangle is

```
if (pt.x >= rect.x && pt.x <= rect.x + rect.width 
  && pt.y >= rect.y && pt.y <= rect.y + rect.height)
```

So all you have to do is calculate the horizontal and vertical distances between your two point,s and test if a 3rd point is within the two using the above formula

Comment: I think this assumes Cartesian coordinates.  In a spherical coordinate system, values wrap-around.   Wouldn't that need to be accounted for?

Comment: @Burt_Harris. Yesm if we were dealing with spherical coordinates. But latitude and longitude are two dimensional. And we are only talking about points on the surface of the planet, not points within the sphere

Comment: @JonasWilms wilms poles are not a problem. How do you think they get a 2 dimentional piece of paper to fit on a globe? The paper itself is not a rectangle, but it is still two dimensional, and using latitude and longitude you can create rectangles on the globe

Comment: @ControlAltDel move one coordinate *onto* the pole. Stuff gets complicated then.

Comment: @Jonas Wilms When you move one coordinate onto an *exact* pole position longitude ceases to exist. So then you can no longer form a rectangle with a second point, or correspondingly ever say if a 3rd point lies within that region (unless I guess that it is on the exact longitude of the 2nd point). This is a special case where the rectangle collapses to a line.

Comment: Your Cartesian-based formula will fail in this case:

a = { lat: 20, lng: 170 }
b = { lat: 10, lng: -170 }
c = { lat: 15, lng: -175 }

Assuming a is the northwestern point, point c is within the rectangle, but your formula would fail because the rectangle crosses the lng=180 line.

Comment: @RobertJ.Walker This is just a question of how you create your rectangle. Yes, these lat/lng cords would need some rectifying to create the proper rectangle. But the way you have formulated this, a would NOT be the northwestern point- it would be the northeastern point, because -170 is less that 175.